# How can I store time in UTC format using groovy?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

Iam trying to store date in UTC format through following code in Groovy but getting error:

```
Document document = new Document("Id",1583084)
        .append("SrcType", 1)
        .append("ActualMonth",1)
        .append("CampaignKey" ,1)
        .append("CampaignOID",11)
        .append("CreatedOn",new Date())
        .append("Date",new Date(),TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
```

Error:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.bson.Document.append() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.Date, sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo) values: [Date, Mon Jan 13 18:11:05 PKT 2020, sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]]
Possible solutions: append(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), spread(), any(), find(), grep()
```

Wht IAm I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with `Instant`?

Comment: Instant? can u plz elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

UTC is not a format, [UTC is the primary time standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), you need to amend your syntax to include the [desired time and date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like:

```
new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy GDK: Date](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.time.Instant.now()
```

returns the current instant from the system UTC clock

```
2020-01-13T14:34:52.858Z
```